# How do I stretch my navigation bar to the width of the window, and have it be responsive?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using a child theme based on the Astra theme for Wordpress, and I've been adding custom css to the stylesheet. However, no matter which element I target, I can't seem to get the nav bar to stretch 100%. I know that its container must also be stretched, but this doesn't solve the issue. I can change just about everything about it except its width.

Like I said, I've tried targeting loads of elements related to this area of the page, as well as many of them at once, including the body tag.

HTML for the relevant section: https://pastebin.com/1x9mVtda

I've noticed that in the css, the box sizing for each element above, including the body, is set to inherit. Could this have something to do with it?

All the elements have this:

```
*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

The nav bar behaves as if it is still contained within a div even if I reset margins and padding to 0 and width to 100% for the body.

Comment: Could you please add the CSS source files.

Comment: Woops, here you go: https://pastebin.com/TPDbFa3G

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.main-navigation {
    -js-display: inline;
    display: inline;
}
.header-main-layout-2 .main-navigation ul {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be doing it. Also, wordpress is failing to recognize "space-evenly" as a value for that property. 

I want to give the nav bar a background color, and whenever I do, it shows that the bar isn't stretching across properly.